# this simple python code, why it doen't work?

Tags: python

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
class obj2 :
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

pList = [obj(1),obj(2),obj(3),obj(4),obj(5)]
list = []

for i in pList:
    obj2(i.a)
    list.append(obj2)

for i in list :
    print(i.a)
```

Hi friend. Im python newBie. I have this code but it doesn't work. 
please teach me.. thank you

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/..py", line 18, in <module>
    print(i.a)
AttributeError: type object 'obj2' has no attribute 'a'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you're mixing up class with instance. and don't use `list` for your variables. And don't call your files `..py`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you throw away the instance of `obj2` that you create in the list, and then append the *class* itself. It should be:

```
for i in pList:
    o2 = obj2(i.a)
    list.append(o2)
```

Note that this would be more obvious if you used standard naming conventions, calling your classes Obj and Obj2.

Comment: Thank you Daniel !